# Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Devices found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Devices may be missing as an ancestor of this view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Hi I am trying to make an EnvironmentObject, but something went wrong and I don't understand what's matter with code. I tried to find the solution, but they didn't help.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Device1View: View {
    var iPhones: [iPhone] = iPhone.allIphones
    @EnvironmentObject var device: Devices
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            ForEach(iPhones, id: \.self){phone in
                Button(phone.model){
                    _ = device.selectedDevice1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

class Devices: ObservableObject{
    @Published  var selectedDevice1 = iPhone.sampleiPhone
    @Published  var selectedDevice2 = iPhone.sampleiPhone
}

struct CompareView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    @StateObject var device = Devices()
    
    var iPhones: [iPhone] = iPhone.allIphones
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200, maximum: 250)),
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200, maximum: 250))
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top){
            ScrollView{...}
            .padding(.top, 55)
            
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10){
                NavigationLink(destination: Device1View()) {
                    Text(device.selectedDevice1.model)
                }
                
                Divider()
            }
            
            .frame(height: 50)
            .background(CustomColor.myColor)
            .cornerRadius(25)
            .shadow(radius: 8, x: 5, y: 5)
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomColor{
    static let myColor = Color("mycolour")
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            CompareView().environmentObject(Devices())
        }
    }
}
```

As I said i tried to find a solution using this FatalError, I have an experience with this problem, but the project was not so big.

Comment: Declare it as a StateObject in your ContentView, `@StateObject var devices = Devices()` and use that property in the modifier.

Comment: I have tried to declare it as @StateObject, but the error is the same.

Comment: Move the injection one line down to the Navigation View closing bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you declare `Devices` in your ContentView, Joakim stated?

```
struct ContentView: View {
@StateObject var device = Devices()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        CompareView().environmentObject(device)
    }
  }
}
```

Then change the declaration in `CompareView` to

```
@EnvironmentObject var device: Devices
```

Comment: Yes, I declare.

Comment: I also added `NavigationLink(destination: Device1View().environmentObject(device)) {
                    Text(device.selectedDevice1.model)
                }` to CompareView and now there is no Error, but there is new problem, selectedDevice1 isn't changing after click.

Comment: Can you post the code you used to set up `iPhone`, so I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I posted the code, there are more structs but they are similar.

Comment: I see that your `selectedDevice1` isn't changing. I think you may want to be using a @Binding, but it's hard for me to determine where the problem is because of the scope of your question. You may try to break down the question to something smaller.

Comment: I think `@EnvironmentObject` only works with `NavigationView`,  not with `NavigationLink`.